# Access DigitalOcean Docker droplet using localhost

Tags: docker

I have recently created a droplet on DigitalOcean to deploy my local development files on DigitalOcean. I would run `docker-compose up` and I can access the site using remote IP address. But I can't access it using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. I need this local access so I can test my development without internet.

I have created the `docker-machine` with `digitalocean` driver like this:

`docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token $DOTOKEN machine-name`

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
data:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-common.yml
    service: data

db:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-common.yml
    service: db
  ports:
    # Publish the port so it's visible on the host, you can access the db directly
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    # Environment variables to configure MySQL on startup.
    # We don't care about commiting these creds to GitHub because they're only
    # for our local development environment
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-root-password-dev
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=guestbook-dev
    - MYSQL_USER=guestbook-admin
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-guestbook-admin-password-dev
  volumes_from:
    # Mount the volumes from the data container to store our MySQL files
    - data

app:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-common.yml
    service: app
  ports:
    # Publish the port so it's visible on the host, you can access the app directly
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    # Link to the db service to store state
    - db:db
  volumes:
    # Mount the app dir in the container as /src so our changes to the app code
    # are also changed in the container
    - ./app:/src
  command: gunicorn --reload app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    # Run Gunicorn to serve app requests and reload on change so we can see our
    # changes to the app code


web:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-common.yml
    service: web
  ports:
    # Publish the port so it's visible on the host
    - "80:80"
  links:
    # Link to the app to serve requests
    - app:app
```

Is there any way to access my docker with localhost?

PS: I am using Mac as my development platform

Comment: Are you trying to access `localhost` from your personal computer or from the droplet?  Only the latter will work, because that's what `localhost` means.

Comment: from my personal computer where I do development work and want to test it

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work.  On your personal computer, "`localhost`", by definition, refers to your personal computer, not the droplet.  Moreover, you can't access your droplet without using the internet, because Digital Ocean droplets aren't part of your computer; they're part of Digital Ocean's servers, and you need the internet to access them.

Comment: but I did `git clone` on my local system and then did `docker-machine` and `docker-compose` to import to droplet. Why I can't access it locally? I previously did this without `docker-machine` and running `docker-compose up` would allow me to access through localhost.

Comment: @codelearner: You can't access your droplet locally *because it doesn't exist locally*.  When you used just `docker-compose` before, you were starting Docker containers on your personal computer, but by using Docker Machine to create Digital Ocean droplets, you've created containers on somebody else's computers ("the cloud") instead.

Comment: I see... so what do you suggest now to access on my localhost and then later I can send to droplet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install docker for your local machine as a development and testing space docker-compose.yml with the command

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox default`

After the configuration is appropriate and ready to deploy, then you create a  `docker-machine` on digitalocean.